# CSS responsive device orientation issue

Tags: android, css

I am developing an app through phonegap and I'm using CSS to make it responsive. Everything is working fine, but in some cases I'd like to use some settings based on the device's orientation. I have no experience with the last one, so I think I am doing something really wrong.

The code below works (it's not based on device orientation).

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 600px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 600px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 600px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 600px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 600px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 600px) { 
/* my styling here */
}
```

The code below does not work (it's based on device orientation, I guess it's wrong). When I use this one it's not styling at all.

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (device-width: 600px) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (device-width: 600px) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (device-width: 600px) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (device-width: 600px) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (device-width: 600px) and (orientation: landscape),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (device-width: 600px) { 
/* my styling here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your needs correctly, the following snippets should work fine for your use.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```

or

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* Styles for Portrait screen */
}
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* Styles for Landscape screen */
}
```

Found at: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-orientation-styles/

Comment: The first one is out, I have to do it only with css. The second one is something I also saw but I don't know how to implement with the rest of my css code for the device based styling.

Comment: You would have a set of CSS for the portrait orientation and a set for landscape. If you need to have more conditions to be met you can continue to use the `and` operator and write multiple media queries.

Comment: I am not sure if I get it well. Could you please write an example including my code? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of fixing the view based on orientation, you can fix the view based on the aspect ratio.**

You can achieve that with **the default css styles** that PhoneGap provides:

```
/* Portrait layout (default) */
.app {
    background:url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat center top; /* 170px x 200px */
    position:absolute;             /* position in the center of the screen */
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    height:50px;                   /* text area height */
    width:225px;                   /* text area width */
    text-align:center;
    padding:180px 0px 0px 0px;     /* image height is 200px (bottom 20px are overlapped with text) */
    margin:-115px 0px 0px -112px;  /* offset vertical: half of image height and text area height */
                                   /* offset horizontal: half of text area width */
}

/* Landscape layout (with min-width) */
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (min-width:400px) {
    .app {
        background-position:left center;
        padding:75px 0px 75px 170px;  /* padding-top + padding-bottom + text area = image height */
        margin:-90px 0px 0px -198px;  /* offset vertical: half of image height */
                                      /* offset horizontal: half of image width and text area width */
    }
}
```

**I recommend you to simply start with the "Hello world" app and keep developing with its structure.**

Answer (score 1):

After all it worked with `min-width` instead of `device-width`, I guess I made a mistake for the first time, that's why I changed it.